# Hyperrectangles with integer diagonals

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

What is the largest value of $n$ for which there exists $n$ (not necessarily distinct) complete squares of natural numbers such that the sum of every subset of it is also a complete square? ( For example, for $n=2$ this sets are two smallest elements of a Pythagorean triplet)

An equivalent form: largest $n$ for which there exists an $n$-dimensional hyperrectangle such that the lengths of diagonals of all of it's faces are integers?

Can one prove that such a set doesn't exist for a large value of $n$, say $1000$?  I worked a while on this seemingly easy problem but couldn't  find the answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick#Perfect_cuboid

Comment: You came back to change 2000 to 1000, when you know it's an open question for $n=3$?

Answer (score 10):

The largest $n$ for which such a thing is known to exist is $n=2$. It is a notorious open problem as to whether such a thing exists for $n=3$. See, for example, the link given by James Cranch in the comments. If it doesn't exist for $n=3$, then it doesn't exist for any $n\ge3$. I don't think there is any $n$ for which it has been proved not to exist.